# Display several youtube video in an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, android-youtube-api, appcompatactivity

I got an Article object that I want to display in my Activity. An article can have:
-Text(s) : 1 at least or several
-Image(s) : 0 or several
-Video(s) : 0 or several

Each element can be anywhere in the article for example :
-Text / Image / Text / Video
-Video / Image / Video / Text
- etc...

After parsing my article, I add programmatically the content I need:  TextView, ImageView, or VideoView(youtube or jwplayer). Actually it works for image and text, but I don't know how I can add several youtube video in a same activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.post);

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llayout_article);

    // Get article to display it
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Article article = intent.getParcelableExtra("articleDetails");

    //add ImageView & TextView
    for (View view : article.getContentSplitInViews(this)) {
        this.linearLayout.addView(view);
    }


    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment frag =
            (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
    src="g2mmUzNSeDM";
    frag.initialize(apiKey, this);
    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment frag2 =
            (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment2);
    src = "nCgQDjiotG0";
    frag2.initialize(apiKey, this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
        youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(src);
        youTubePlayer.play();
    }
}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
    // YouTube error
    String errorMessage = youTubeInitializationResult.toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);
}
```

My current xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewId"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llayout_article"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
            android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


        <fragment
            android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
            android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Later I want to add programmaticaly the fragment tag in my XML for each video found in the Article Object.

Actually, there is 2 players in my activity, but only one is playing the video, and action in every players (play/pause/full screen) will do the same thing in the 2 players.

[image: android youtube api]

Comment: https://androidtutorialmagic.wordpress.com/my-mini-project/multiple-youtube-video-in-recyclerviewlistview-in-android/

Comment: Nice tutorial, but I don't really want to use youtubeStandAlonePlayer. Is there a way to display the several video, and then play the right one by clicking "play button" ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to distinguish from two providers by id in onInitializationSuccess().

If the provider is the frag1, call youTubePlayer.loadVideo("g2mmUzNSeDM") 
else if the provider is the frag2, call youTubePlayer.loadVideo("nCgQDjiotG0")

(You can add YouTubePlayerView programmatically to your layout if your activity extends YoutubeBaseActivity)

Comment: How can I know what is the id of the frag1 provider before entering in the onInitializationSuccess? I need to know which src I have to load if I see a specific Providersid
Actually I can't use YoutubePlayerView because I extends appCompatActivity, so I read that use YoutubePlayerFragment is the solution.

Comment: Id would be an example. You can compare easily. if (frag1.equals(provider)) { // TODO: call loadVideo } else if (frag2.equals(provider)) { // TODO: call loadVideo }

Comment: it doesn't change anything, even with this condition, the only video played is the last loaded...